# Metamask Out of gas error

Tags: transactions

[image][image: Screensho]I'm unable to send ethereum from my Metamask..its showing error as "insufficient fund for gas" despite having 5 ethereums in my account.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to congestion caused by cryptokitties, the situation seems to be have been resolved, for more information go to, [Link](https://medium.com/metamask/metamask-cryptokitty-performance-update-83d851af0147).

Comment: Network congestion does not cause out-of-gas - your tx simply sits in the txpool for a while and not get picked up. OOG is caused by not enough gas limit, or tx fails due to throws