# Metamask- Out of gas error

Tags: bug

I have a question about my Ethereum Stack Exchange post: [Metamask Out of gas error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32521/metamask-out-of-gas-error)

I cannot transfer Ethereum from Metamask. It gives me out of gas error. I was trying to transfer just 1 of 5 ethers in my Metamask[image: Image 1[![Image 2]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIf6j.jpg)